# How are dynamic cronjobs inserted into cron_schedule

Tags: cron, schedule

The timing for a number of Magento's core cron tasks such as sitemap, stock alert notifications and log cleaning can be adjusted via the admin's System Config. This means they are not defined inside the `cronjob` node of a module's config.xml however they do get written into the `cron_schedule` table like other jobs.

How does the cron scheduler find those jobs? My guess is that there is an event thrown during the schedule generation, but I can't see any instances of `dispatchEvent` within Mage_Cron.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These kind of cronjobs have a backend model that is called when the cron settings are called. This model inserts the cron job run time in `core_config_data` and the cron schedule reads it from there.
Let's take as example the sitemap cron. The field 'frequency' has this backend model (see `app/code/code/Mage/Sitemap/etc/system.xml`):

```
<backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_sitemap_cron</backend_model>
```

When the frequency is saved (and the rest of the fields with it) this method is called: `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_Sitemap_Cron::_afterSave()`.
This inserts in the table `core_config_data` the cron expression with this path `crontab/jobs/sitemap_generate/schedule/cron_expr`.
This value is read in `Mage_Cron_Model_Observer::_generateJobs` and added to the `cron_schedule`