# Using dynamic info on config.xml

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, xml, configuration

How i can set up cron time on config.xml on my module to magento??

Something like::

```
 <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <captcha_delete_old_attempts>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr><!--dynamic info here--></cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>captcha/observer::deleteOldAttempts</model>
                </run>
            </captcha_delete_old_attempts>
            <captcha_delete_expired_images>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr><!--dynamic info here--></cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>captcha/observer::deleteExpiredImages</model>
                </run>
            </captcha_delete_expired_images>

        </jobs>
    </crontab>
```

Comment: What you mean by dinamic info? Cron job should be scheduled in admin->configuration? Or simple: every hour, every 5 minut, every day ...?

Comment: Follow this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4838/how-are-dynamic-cronjobs-inserted-into-cron-schedule and http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: I mean, i need to do this cron configurable by the user. Some times the user should need the cron runs every 15 minutes, or some times he'll need every hour. So, the user set up on system.xml the cron time frequency and this should work.

Comment: @mageUz this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4838/how-are-dynamic-cronjobs-inserted-into-cron-schedule does the job.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps a bit with some explanations: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/4838/146

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my example:
**1.Your cron configuration in config.xml:**

```
 <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <uzkart_fetch_payment>
                <run>
                    <model>uzkart/observer::uzkart_fetch_payment</model>
                </run>
            </uzkart_fetch_payment>
        </jobs>
  </crontab>
```

**2.Create cron time configuration in your system.xml:**

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <uzkart_standard translate="label" module="uzkart">
                    <label>Uzkart Standard Payment</label>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <!--maybe another fields here-->
                        <frequency translate="label">
                            <label>Frequency</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_cron_frequency</source_model>
                            <!-- Custom backend model which saves cron configuration -->
                            <backend_model>uzkart/adminhtml_system_config_backend_payment_cron</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment>
                        </frequency>
                        <!-- Cron job time -->
                        <time translate="label">
                            <label>Start Time</label>
                            <frontend_type>time</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>201</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </time>
                    </fields>
                </uzkart_standard>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

It shows following configuration in admin:
[image]

**3.Backend model** 
`<backend_model>uzkart/adminhtml_system_config_backend_payment_cron</backend_model>` 
refers to this model:

```
class SSD_Uzkart_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Backend_Payment_Cron extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    const CRON_STRING_PATH = 'crontab/jobs/uzkart_fetch_payment/schedule/cron_expr';
    const CRON_MODEL_PATH = 'crontab/jobs/uzkart_fetch_payment/run/model';

    protected function _afterSave()
    {
        $time = $this->getData('groups/uzkart_standard/fields/time/value');
        $frequncy = $this->getData('groups/uzkart_standard/frequency/value');

        $frequencyDaily = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Cron_Frequency::CRON_DAILY;
        $frequencyWeekly = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Cron_Frequency::CRON_WEEKLY;
        $frequencyMonthly = Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Cron_Frequency::CRON_MONTHLY;

        $cronDayOfWeek = date('N');

        $cronExprArray = array(
            intval($time[1]),                                   # Minute
            intval($time[0]),                                   # Hour
            ($frequncy == $frequencyMonthly) ? '1' : '*',       # Day of the Month
            '*',                                                # Month of the Year
            ($frequncy == $frequencyWeekly) ? '1' : '*',        # Day of the Week
        );

        $cronExprString = join(' ', $cronExprArray);

        try {
            Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
                ->load(self::CRON_STRING_PATH, 'path')
                ->setValue($cronExprString)
                ->setPath(self::CRON_STRING_PATH)
                ->save();
            Mage::getModel('core/config_data')
                ->load(self::CRON_MODEL_PATH, 'path')
                ->setValue((string) Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::CRON_MODEL_PATH))
                ->setPath(self::CRON_MODEL_PATH)
                ->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception(Mage::helper('cron')->__('Unable to save the cron expression.'));
        }
    }
}
```

**4.When you save your configuration in admin**, it will generate following lines in `core_config_data` table of magento and magento cron scheduler will use this config:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer. It's kinda hard to find some good stuff about that. You should write a tutorial about this =] Congrats

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/

```
*     *     *   *    *
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

For example,

```
<!-- Run at 02:01 every Friday -->
<cron_expr>1 2 * * 5</cron_expr>
```

Some things to keep in mind:

1. The schedule depends highly on how frequently you are running `cron.sh/cron.php` on your system. If it is only run every 15 mins then you will never see something run more frequently than that.
2. Pay attention to the timezone
3. There are additional cron settings in System > Config > Advanced > System which control scheduling of cron tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, but i need to let user configure how the cron will run. It's possible?

Comment: @Guerra If you want it to be configured by the user then follow the example of `Mage_Sitemap`. There is no `<cron_expr>` in etc/config.xml, but rather there is a configuration option in `etc/system.xml` which sets the `crontab/jobs/sitemap_generate/schedule/cron_expr` record in the `core_config_data` database table.